# Font-awesome few icons are not supported in swift 4.2 in macOS 10

Tags: swift, font-awesome, notsupportedexception

I have added Font-Awesome in swift 4.2 but few icons are not supported showing box with question mark.

I installed the pod 'FontAwesome.swift' and imported it and try to use it as per this library. I m following code from this link https://github.com/thii/FontAwesome.swift

`cell.imgChild.image = UIImage.fontAwesomeIcon(name: .child, style: .brands, textColor: .black, size: CGSize(width: 30, height: 30))`

I want to set icon as per my requirement but i m not getting this. Can anyone help me in this all I m getting is this.[image]

Comment: I would suggest to open a ticket in the GitHub repo